# How can i limit/gate memory usage in go unit test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, memory, go

Is there a way to limit the amount of memory usage/growth during a unit test in golang?

For example, in java, we can do:

```
long before = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()

// allocate a bunch of memory
long after = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()

Assert.AssertTrue(before-after < 100)
```

(roughly) to assert that we didn't use more than 100 bytes.

Comment: Use -benchmem flag (and have some benchmarks). Something like "free memory" is not a suitable metric in Go so you won't be able to do the exact same.

Answer (score 5):

Use Go benchmarks to analyze memory usage. For example:

`mem.go`:

```
package mem

func memUse() {
    var stack [1024]byte
    heap := make([]byte, 64*1024)
    _, _ = stack, heap
}
```

`mem_test.go`:

```
package mem

import "testing"

func BenchmarkMemUse(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        memUse()
    }
    b.StopTimer()
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: mem
BenchmarkMemUse-4     200000      8188 ns/op       65536 B/op       1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      mem 1.745s
```

The `memUse` function makes one heap allocation of 65536 (64*1024) bytes. Stack allocations are cheap and local to a function so we don't count them.

Instead of the `ReportAllocs` method you could use the `-benchmem` flag. For example,

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem
```

References:

[Go: Package testing: Benchmarks](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/)

[Command go: Description of testing functions](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_functions)

[Command go: Description of testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags)

---

If you really must apply a memory limit during a Go `testing` package Test function, try using [`runtime.MemStats`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStats). For example,

```
func TestMemUse(t *testing.T) {
    defer runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1))
    var start, end runtime.MemStats
    runtime.GC()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&start)
    memUse()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&end)
    alloc := end.TotalAlloc - start.TotalAlloc
    limit := uint64(64 * 1000)
    if alloc > limit {
        t.Error("memUse:", "allocated", alloc, "limit", limit)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test
--- FAIL: TestMemUse (0.00s)
    mem_test.go:18: memUse: allocated 65536 limit 64000
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    mem 0.003s
```